# Dynamically add property to Yii CComponent based object from within the object in PHP?

Tags: php, yii

In PHP you can do the following:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->$newPropertyName = $value;
```

To dynamically add new property to the object. However when I try to do that:

```
$this->$newPropertyName = $value;
```

It doesn't work. How can I dynamically add new property from within the object?

UPDATE:

My class inherits from Yii CFormModel class. CFormModel overrides the PHP `__set` method so it causes the problem. How to do what I want? How to use default `__set` method?

Comment: $foo->newPropertyName = $value;

Comment: @user3234352 - dollar is needed as new property name comes from variable

Comment: It's not nonsense. $newPropretyName is a variable that holds the new property name. I don't want to create property `newPropertyName`. The property name is unknown to the developer. It is going to come from database.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->newPropertyName = $value;
```

can be called from **inside** any method of a class. in public scope it's that way:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->newPropertyName = $value;
```

when using `$this->` you don't put dollar signs.

**However**, you can try and force php to evaluate your variable (as in can vary) property name before assigning it to your property like this:

```
$foo->{$newPropertyName} = $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work dynamically, there must be a bug in your code (maybe mispelling `$newPropertyName`)?

```
class Foo {

    public function addProperty($newPropertyName, $value) {
        $this->$newPropertyName = $value;
    }

}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->addProperty('weather', 'raining');
echo $foo->weather;
```

Comment: Hm, I just got the "Property Foo.xxx not defined" error. My PHP v. is 5.4.16 so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Ah, I guess it might be because PHP magic __set ang __get methods are overriden by base class. That makes things more complicated... The base class is yii CFormModel.